# How will Ubuntu 18.04 installation will handle the partitioning if I choose Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, partitioning, installation

My goal is to dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10 Home. What have I have done so far is:

1. Downloaded ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
2. Used Rufus and created a bootable USB device.
3. Turned off Secure Boot.
4. Selected to boot from USB in the boot menu.
5. Chose *Install Ubuntu*.
6. Followed Ubuntu installation steps until the *Installation Type* screen.
7. Here I stopped as I don't know what will happen if I choose *Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10*?

I was thinking to choose Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10, but then what will happen? Will Ubuntu get installed in C: or some other drive? I want to know how Ubuntu will handle the partitioning if I choose *Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10*.

- Please do not suggest to choose *Something else*.
- Please do not suggest to free up some appropriate space using Disk Management in Windows 10 before the installation.
- My main objective is to find out how Ubuntu will handle the partitioning if I choose *Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose the *Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10* option form the Installation type screen of the Ubuntu installer it will continue until you get to a screen with a divider that you can move back and forth to allocate space on the drive between Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.

Installation type:

[image: Installation type]

Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10:

[image: Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10] 
<sup>**Allocate drive space by dragging the divider**</sup>

Comment: Is there any complete video or instructions available for dual booting windows and ubuntu18.04 from the first step of downloading iso file to complete installation of ubuntu18.04 in which "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10:" is used without use of Windows Disk Management?

Comment: [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/q/221835/) is the best resource to start with.

Comment: Is there any graphical bootloader available that shows windows 10 and ubuntu18.04 like easybcd but for bios mode=UEFI?

Comment: In case anything in the bootloader breaks because of an update in Windows 10 or any other reason, the default grub bootloader is the easiest to fix for two reasons: 1. grub is open source. 2. grub can be repaired automatically by GUI programs such as Boot-Repair. If you choose to stay with grub you can customize the grub boot menu with the [Grub Customizer](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/03/11/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-18-04-lts/) application.

Comment: Can it be customized to load only WIndows10 unless explicitly selected to load ubuntu?

Comment: That being said some people have successfully modified Windows Boot Manager to be the default boot manager for an Ubuntu / Windows dual boot. Yes, grub can be modified without even installing Grub Customizer to make Windows 10 the default entry in the GRUB boot menu instead of Ubuntu. If you do nothing the computer automatically boots to the default boot entry after 10 seconds. The 10 second wait time can also be changed.

Comment: Karen as you say that some people have successfully modified Windows Boot Manager to be the default boot manager for an Ubuntu / Windows dual boot, then in this case whatever windows update i install , Windows Boot Manager should not  break?

Comment: For new Ubuntu users I strongly recommend staying with the default grub bootloader. I don't recommend making Windows Boot Manager the default bootloader for new Ubuntu users.

Answer (score 0):

> Will ubuntu automatically handle all paritions stuff?

Yes,it will attempt to repartition your drive on which Windows is installed and will try to allocate the free space to linux

> Will ubuntu get installed in c:? or some other drive? I want to know
>   how ubuntu handle will partitions if i choose Install ubuntu alongside
>   Windows 10.

No it will shrink the the size of c: drive and will create a ext4 partition which will be used by linux

Also it will install the Grub on complete hard drive (i.e will over Windows bootloader) and everytime you will be presented with option to choose which is Operating system to boot.

I hope all questions are answered and if something is left will edit and add for sure!!!

Comment: I have C: of 83.8GB of which 41.4GB is used in windows 10 home.If i choose to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS alongside Windows 10 Home, how much space will ubuntu use approximately according to you ? Just give a rough idea . And should i incrase the space of C: before installation?If yes;then how much should i increase according to you?I know you would not be able to give exact value to my question, So any anwser would be helpfull.

Comment: If you choose to install alongside you will get something like 'Allocate drive space by dragging the slider below' Refer to get an idea :https://askubuntu.com/questions/150550/installing-ubuntu-with-windows-which-is-left-and-right-when-allocating-space ;What do you mean by ' should I increase the space of c: before installation?' (do you have any unlocated space,if yes then you can) ;And Root partition should be of about 10 GB atleast

Comment: To user52599 -You said "No it will shrink the the size of c: drive and will create a ext4 partition which will be used by linux" ,so I asked ' should I increase the space of c: before installation?'

Comment: Do you have any unlocated space after c:? If yes and don't plan to do anything with it then you can surely do that !!?